# Keyboard shortcut to highlight text in a web page

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I was wondering if there is any keyboard shortcut there to highlight text(may be lines or paragraph) from a web page(in IE or firefox). Using mouse we will have to select the whole line/text, sometimes very cumbersome. What I need is select the text from a web page and copy the text to say a notepad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is caret browsing.

IE 8 onwards:

1. Press F7.
2. Click the Page button, and then click Caret Browsing.
3. Click Yes to turn on Caret Browsing.

To turn on Caret Browsing for all new windows and tabs

1. Click the Tools button, and then click Internet Options.
2. Click the Advanced tab.
3. Under Accessibility, select the Enable Caret Browsing for new windows and tabs check box, and then click OK.

Source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/How-can-I-select-text-and-move-around-a-webpage-with-my-keyboard?SignedIn=1

Comment: Unfortunately it is not available in IE7. It is introduced as an accessibility feature in IE8.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following method to save a lot of mouse scrolling. Place the mouse cursor at the start of the block of text you want to select and do a left-click - don't worry if you don't see a vertical cursor line appear at that location. Then place the mouse cursor at the end of the block of text you want to select, using the web browser scrollbar first if necessary to bring that location into view, and do SHIFT + left-click. When I do this in Firefox, the selected block of text is highlighted with the blue background, ready for copying - give it a go in IE, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For me (running windows 10) in Chrome I use CTRL + ALT and then select the text.